# How to copy a file multiple time in php

Tags: php

I have to copy a file multiple time in a folder. I have a image in a folder with name 1.jpg. I want to copy same image(1.jpg) up to ten times and rename it with 2.jpg,3jpg and so on. Please help.

Comment: http://php.net/copy It is the first result when you google "*php copy file*". Put some effort into it before asking for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php

$file = '1.jpg';
for($i=2;$i<=10;$i++)
{
    copy($file, $i.'.jpg'));
}

?>
```